# Asynchronous queueing of speech synthesis requests with sequential audio output

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, amazon-polly

I want to put text that arrives asynchronously into a queue that first generates an audio stream with Amazon Polly, and then plays the resulting audio streams **sequentially** as soon as they arrive, but **without** blocking the entry of new text into the queue.

To test this system, I read in text that is written to the console. In my current implementation, the addition of new text to the console is blocked while the audio plays. Ideally, it should also possible to stop both the audio that is currently played as well as remove any queued speech synthesis requests and audio plays.

I know that the correct implementation involves Threading and Tasks somehow, but I currently have no idea how to do this properly as I am completely new to C#, threading, and asynchronous programming. Please keep in mind that the only available implementation for the Amazon Polly speech synthesis (SynthesizeSpeechAsync) is asynchronous. Ultimately, this code is supposed to work in conjunction with the Unity Engine to play text in-game via different text-to-speech services as an accessibility tool for people who have a hard time reading a lot of text on computer screens. For now, getting it to work with console inputs is fine.

Here's what I got so far. First a class that generates audio from text:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Amazon.Polly;
using Amazon.Polly.Model;
using NAudio.Wave;

namespace UnityTTS;

public class PollyVoiceUnity : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static string awsAccessKey = "myKey";
    private static string awsAccessSecret = "mySecretKey";
    private static AmazonPollyClient client;

    public static void Init()
    {
        client = new AmazonPollyClient(awsAccessKey, awsAccessSecret, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest2);
    }

    private async static Task<SynthesizeSpeechResponse> GetSpeechResponse(string s)
    {
        SynthesizeSpeechRequest synthesizeSpeechRequest = new SynthesizeSpeechRequest()
        {
            OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Pcm,
            VoiceId = VoiceId.Brian,
            TextType = TextType.Text,
            Text = s,
            SampleRate = "16000"
        };
        SynthesizeSpeechResponse synthesizeSpeechResponse = await client.SynthesizeSpeechAsync(synthesizeSpeechRequest);
        return synthesizeSpeechResponse;
    }

    private static void PlayAudio(SynthesizeSpeechResponse response)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            response.AudioStream.CopyTo(ms);

            byte[] buf = ms.GetBuffer();
            var source = new BufferedWaveProvider(new WaveFormat(16000, 16, 1));
            source.ReadFully = false;
            source.AddSamples(buf, 0, buf.Length);

            using (WaveOutEvent waveOut = new WaveOutEvent())
            {
                waveOut.Init(source);

                AutoResetEvent stopped = new AutoResetEvent(false);
                waveOut.PlaybackStopped += (object sender, StoppedEventArgs e) => { stopped.Set(); };
                waveOut.Play();
                stopped.WaitOne();
            }
        }
    }

    public async static Task AddSpeechToQueue(string s)
    {
        SynthesizeSpeechResponse response = await GetSpeechResponse(s);
        PlayAudio(response);
        return;
    }
}
```

and then a main class for testing:

```
using UnityTTS

class Program
{
    public async static Task Main()
    {
        PollyVoiceUnity.Init();
        string? input = "Initialized.";
        while (input != "stop")
        {
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input != "stop")
            {
                await PollyVoiceUnity.AddSpeechToQueue(input);
            }          
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to dive into threading in Unity, and not coroutines? Unity is single-threaded, but you can spin up native C# threads in parallel if you really want to. Interacting with those threads also restricts you to raw data types and no Unity objects/functions.

Comment: Hey, not sure at all. It's just that most of what I found in Google searches mentioned threading, so I thought that might be what I need. Knowing that I should probably be using coroutines instead is already quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this thread where it explains how you can integrate Amazon Polly in Unity using Coroutines, which is easier. You can try doing a deep research and find something else:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/guide-integrating-amazon-polly-unity-mythili-pitchika/

Also you can have a look there:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html
https://answers.unity.com/questions/503932/how-to-cycle-coroutine-in-c-say-every-1-sec.html